# HttpUrlConnection response code always returns -1

Tags: http, httpurlconnection

I have created my server in amazon ec2 instance. Through my android app i am connecting to the server with HttpUrlConnection. But i get response code as -1. Does anyone has any idea ?? Here is my code.
private  String getHttpResponse(final String srcUrl) {

```
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(srcUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        mETag = readETagFromPrefForCategory();

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("If-None-Match", mETag);

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("xyz", "abc".toCharArray());
            }
        });

        urlConnection.connect();

        mETag =  urlConnection.getHeaderField("ETag");

        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED) {
            Log.v("http","not modifed");
            return readLocalJson();
        }

        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Bad response [" + urlConnection.getResponseCode() + "] from (" + srcUrl + ")");
            return null;
        }}//end of try block
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer in this post seemed to solve it for a few people:

[Android Https Status code -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994073/android-https-status-code-1)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I tried System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false"); but sadly it didn't work for me :(.. Any other help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your headers HTTP version is not properly formatted. Check this SO link where I have answered a similar question which worked for me.

[Java Http~URLConnection response code -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432976/java-httpurlconnection-response-code-1/28393738#28393738)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting "Content-Type" on a GET request?