# HttpUrlConnection returns -1 status code

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have problem with connecting to my server. Following code returns -1 as response code and null as response message.

```
  protected Boolean doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {
    URL url = null;
    String load = params[0].jobj.toString();
    try {
        url = new URL(params[0].serverUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(3000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        osw.write(load);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

        if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()==200 && urlConnection.getResponseMessage().contains("true") ) return true;
        else return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

While debbuging url and body content (which is load in code) are correct. When I try to connect with the server using those params with Fiddler it works perfectly and I get 200 status code. Do you have any ideas what is wrong?

Im passing jData object as the jobj:

```
        JSONObject User=new JSONObject();
        JSONObject Mobile=new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jData=new JSONObject();
        try {
            User.put ("UserLogin", "test");
            User.put ("UserPassword", "test");
            Mobile.put ("MobileIDD", IDD);
            Mobile.put("MobileToken", token);
            jData.put("Mobile", Mobile);
            jData.put("User", User);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

@EDIT
Solution with `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false")` didnt help.

Comment: Add the code where you determine the response code and the respinse message and the returned page. Show `load`  type. Maybe you should show `load` content.

Comment: I edited first post. Thank you

Comment: Please put all code in one code block in the right sequence. You did not show code to read the returned page yet.

Comment: Done. Im checking status code of response message after osw.close().

Comment: Did you say that urlConnection.getResponseMessage() returns null? If so then the .contains() call would provoke a NullPointerException.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Https Status code -1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994073/android-https-status-code-1)

Comment: Well, it doesn't. [link]http://puu.sh/ndNdl/915ec81f60.png The solution with Keep alive doesnt help.

Comment: Look for this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7994180/4848308

Comment: It indeed does not help if you dont answer my questions.

Comment: I have answered your question. I said getResponseMessage returns null and I attached a screenshot from debugging. I dont get any nullpointerexception anyway.

Comment: No help I suppose? :(

Comment: `If so then the .contains() call would provoke a NullPointerException`. This still is the case. If you dont get a NullPointerException then urlConnection.getResponseMessage() is not null as you said it is.  It would be equal to calling `null.contains()`.

Comment: Ok. The exception is not there indeed as that is for code 200. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Remove setChunkedStreamingMode.

Comment: And it is time you tell about your server. And what the server gets from your post.

Comment: I solved problem. Solution is in next post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was in this line:

```
if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()==200 && urlConnection.getResponseMessage().contains("true") ) return true;
```

When I changed it to:

```
int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
if (code==200.....)
```

It started working.