# HttpURLConnection response code -1

Tags: java, php, android

Hi, I'm trying to connect to my PHP file on the localhost server with my Android application using `AsyncTask`. The problem is, when executing the application I got -1 as a response code and it (the debugger) doesn't state what the problem is.

I tried to apply the solution I found here, [Android Https Status code -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994073/android-https-status-code-1), but it didn't work out for me.

**PHPConnecteur.java**

```
public class PHPConnecteur extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

   private HashMap<String, String> parameters;
   private String phpToCall;

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    //System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/test.php"); // here is your URL path
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000 );
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 );
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            // Pass data to onPostExecute method
            return (result.toString());
        }
        else {
            return conn.getResponseMessage();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return "erreur de communication avec le serveur";
    }
}
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

  echo "Yeah, success!"    

?>
```

I don't think the problem comes from PHP. So anyone know what the problem is? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The ``Exception e`` tells you a lot, yet you choose to ignore it...

Comment: It says `Failed to connect to the server`, but the weird thing is when i typed the url in web browser, it works perfectly @f1sh

Comment: Just have to ask, is the Android app running in an emulator on the same machine or is it on some other device with it's own network interface/ip-address?

Comment: Try it in a browser on your device instead. Or using an emulator? You cannot use 127.0.0.1 of course.

Comment: It's running on an emulator on the same machine @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Can I know why we can't use 127.0.0.1? @greenapps

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the device itself. So your app running on a phone would try to connect with a server on your phone then.

Comment: Use 10.0.2.2 when running on emulator.

Comment: take a see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips

Comment: Ok, i got the logic here, but why use 10.0.2.2 instead? Btw, it's still gives me the same error @greenapps  EDIT: Just read about it why...thanks

Comment: Try your url in a browser on the emulator.

Comment: `It says Failed to connect to the server, ` Where? Post the logcat.

Comment: After changing it to 10.0.2.2, it works actually...I mistype the address actually, my bad sorry...Thanks again for the help @greenapps

Comment: You forget Magnus!